# No Connecting Path found between reference frames

Tags: vector, physics, sympy

I'm using the sympy module in jupyter notebook to do some calculations with reference frames. I only rotate around the z-axis by an angle av. The idea is as follows:

- W is the world frame
- V is the vehicle frame, world frame rotated over the z-axis by pi - av
- u is frame v, rotated over a 90 degrees angle over the z-axis

I'm using the following code:

```python
from sympy import *
init_printing()
av = symbols('\\alpha_v')

# Reference frames
from sympy.physics.vector import *
# World frame
W = ReferenceFrame('W')
# Vehicle frame
v = ReferenceFrame('v')
v.orient(W,'Axis',[pi-av,W.z])
display('Rotation matrix from W to v:')
display(W.dcm(v)) <-- Check if frames are still coupled

# u frame
u = v
display(W.dcm(v))  <-- Check if frames are still coupled
u.orient(u,'Axis',[pi/2,u.z])
display(W.dcm(v)) <-- Check if frames are still coupled, from here on error!
display('Rotation matrix from w to u:')
display(u.dcm(w))
```

After the rotation of u, the link between the v and W frame is broken. I get the following output:

[image: Output]

The error at the end is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-72d62c7921df> in <module>()
     17 display(W.dcm(v))
     18 u.orient(u,'Axis',[pi/2,u.z])
---> 19 display(W.dcm(v))
     20 display('Rotation matrix from w to u:')
     21 display(u.dcm(w))

c:\python\python35\lib\site-packages\sympy\physics\vector\frame.py in dcm(self, otherframe)
    409         if otherframe in self._dcm_cache:
    410             return self._dcm_cache[otherframe]
--> 411         flist = self._dict_list(otherframe, 0)
    412         outdcm = eye(3)
    413         for i in range(len(flist) - 1):

c:\python\python35\lib\site-packages\sympy\physics\vector\frame.py in _dict_list(self, other, num)
    254             return outlist[0]
    255         raise ValueError('No Connecting Path found between ' + self.name +
--> 256                          ' and ' + other.name)
    257 
    258     def _w_diff_dcm(self, otherframe):

ValueError: No Connecting Path found between W and v
```

Thus by rotating u I break the connection between W and v? I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Server Information:
You are using Jupyter notebook.

The version of the notebook server is: 5.6.0
The server is running on this version of Python:
Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Edit: The problem can be solved by:

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()
av = symbols('\\alpha_v')

# Reference frames
from sympy.physics.vector import *
# World frame
W = ReferenceFrame('W')
display(W)

# Vehicle frame
v = ReferenceFrame('v')
v.orient(W,'Axis',[pi-av,W.z])
display('Rotation matrix from W to v:')
display(W.dcm(v))
display(W.dcm(v))

# u frame
u = ReferenceFrame('u')
u.orient(v,'axis',[pi/2,v.z])
display(u.dcm(v))
display(W.dcm(v))
```

I thought that u = v was making a copy of v in the variable u. This does not work and causes the problem. Defining u as a referenceframe and orienting it with respect to v afterwards is the proper way to do.

The only question that still remains is, how to make a copy if you want two identical reference frames? Is the only way something like this?

```
u = ReferenceFrame('u')
u.orient(v,'axis',[0,v.z])
```